# SQL join table with it self given partition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I have a table like the following:

```
table
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          a          |         b        |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          1          |         34       |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          1          |         25       |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          1          |         72       |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          2          |         10       |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          2          |         12       |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          2          |         32       |
    |---------------------|------------------|
```

What I basically want is in SQL to join the table with itself based on a, the final should look like:

```
final_table
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          b1         |         b2       |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          34         |         25       |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          34         |         72       |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          25         |         72       |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          10         |         12       |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          10         |         32       |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          12         |         32       |
    |---------------------|------------------|
```

I want to find all pairs which have the same id.

Note: the order b1 and b2 is arbitrary, it can be in any order as long as each pair appears only once

Comment: is it arbitrary which is b1 and which is b2?

Comment: Yes, it can be any order, as long as each pair appears only once

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: It is MySQL, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you need (the lower value in the pair will be b1)

```
SELECT
   y1.b as b1,
   y2.b as b2 
FROM
   YourTable y1 
   JOIN
      YourTable y2 
      ON y1.a = y2.a 
      AND y1.b < y2.b
```

Comment: Great! It solved it, thanks. Is there any difference between doing the `y1.b < y2.b` together with the ON or after with a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: No, it makes no difference for an inner join but if the predicate references columns from both tables I put it in the join, otherwise I put it in the WHERE